# GraphQL returns null for update and delete mutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-django

I am using graphene-django library for integrating GraphQL Schema into my Django application.

I have implemented Queries; get all and get specific, as well as implemented create, update and delete Mutations. All endpoints are working as expected except for the **update** and **delete**.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ("sierra leone",  "Sierra Leone"),
    ("guinea", "Guinea"),
)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255)
    abreviation = models.CharField(_("Abreviation"), max_length=10)
    label = models.TextField(_("Label"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    school_id = models.CharField(_("School ID"), max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    adresse_line_1 = models.CharField(_("Adresse Line 1"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    adresse_line_2 = models.CharField(_("Adresse Line 2"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_("Phone number"), max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"))
    website = models.CharField(_("Website"), max_length=50, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(_("Logo"), upload_to='logo/', blank=True)
    small_logo = models.ImageField(_("Small Logo"), upload_to='logo/', blank=True, null=True)
    site_favicon = models.ImageField(_("Favicon"), upload_to='logo/', blank=True, null=True)
```

And here is the code for my update and delete mutations:

```
class SchoolType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = (
            "name",
            "abreviation",
            "label",
            "school_id",
            "adresse_line_1",
            "adresse_line_2",
            "city",
            "country",
            "phone_number",
            "email",
            "website",
            "logo",
            "small_logo",
            "site_favicon",
        )
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        convert_choices_to_enum = False

class UpdateSchoolMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    school = graphene.Field(SchoolType)
    success = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String(required=True)
        name = graphene.String()
        abreviation = graphene.String()
        label = graphene.String()
        school_id = graphene.String()
        adresse_line_1 = graphene.String()
        adresse_line_2 = graphene.String()
        city = graphene.String()
        country = graphene.String()
        phone_number = graphene.String()
        email = graphene.String()
        website = graphene.String()
        logo = Upload()
        small_logo = Upload()
        site_favicon = Upload()

    @classmethod
    def mutate(self, info, id, **kwargs):
        id = int(from_global_id(id)[1])

        try:
            school = School.objects.get(pk=id)
        except School.DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception("School does not exist".format(id))

        for field, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(school, field, value)

        school.save()
        return UpdateSchoolMutation(school=school, success=True)


class DeleteSchoolMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    success = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(self, info, id, **kwargs):
        id = int(from_global_id(id)[1])
        
        try:
            school = School.objects.get(pk=id)
        except School.DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception("School does not exist".format(id))

        school.archived = True
        school.save()
        return DeleteSchoolMutation(success=True)
```

When I carry out the delete mutation as such:

```
mutation {
  deleteSchool(id: "U2Nob29sVHlwZToy") {
    success
  }
}
```

I get the following results;

```
{
  "data": {
    "deleteSchool": {
      "success": null
    }
  }
}
```

The same goes for the update mutation. These are the versions I am using incase if it helps:

```
django==4.0.8
graphene-django==3.0.0
django-filter==22.1
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.4
graphene-file-upload==1.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the `mutate` method. The mutate method requires 3 initial arguments `cls`, `root`, and `info` before the custom user arguments

Therefore this Delete Mutation:

```
class DeleteSchoolMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    success = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(self, info, id, **kwargs):
        # Delete School
```

Would become:

```
class DeleteSchoolMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    success = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(self, root, info, id, **kwargs):
        # Delete School
```